# Pytorch : AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cuda'

Tags: python, pytorch, python-3.7

```
import torch
import models
model_names = sorted(name for name in models.__dict__
                     if name.islower() and not name.startswith("__")
                     and callable(models.__dict__[name]))
model = models.__dict__['resnet18']
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model,device_ids = [0])  #PROBLEM CAUSING LINE
model.to('cuda:0')
```

To run this code you need to clone this repository : https://github.com/SoftwareGift/FeatherNets_Face-Anti-spoofing-Attack-Detection-Challenge-CVPR2019.git

Please run this piece of code inside the root folder of the cloned directory.

I am getting the follow error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cuda'`
I have tried using torch.device object as well for the same function and it results in the same error. 
Please ask for any other details that are required. PyTorch newbie here 
python:3.7 pytorch:1.3.1

Comment: torch.cuda.is_available()   ?

Comment: Try replacing `model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model,device_ids = [0])` with `model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model() ,device_ids = [0])` (notice the `()` after `model` inside `DataParallel`)

Comment: @Jatentaki Worked like a charm ! Can you please explain the difference ? What does replacing `model` with `model()` change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model,device_ids = [0])
```

with

```
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model(), device_ids=[0])
```

(notice the `()` after model inside `DataParallel`). The difference is simple: the `models` module contains classes/functions which create models and not *instances* of models. If you trace the imports, you'll find that `models.__dict__['resnet18']` resolves to [this](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/227027d5abc8eacb110c93b5b5c2f4ea5dd401d6/torchvision/models/resnet.py#L228) function. Since `DataParallel` wraps an instance, not a class itself, it is incompatible. The `()` calls this model building function/class constructor to create an instance of this model.

A much simpler example of this would be the following

```
class MyNet(nn.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        self.linear = nn.Linear(4, 4)
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)

model = nn.DataParallel(MyNet) # this is what you're doing
model = nn.DataParallel(MyNet()) # this is what you should be doing
```

Your error message complains that `function` (since `model` without the `()` is of type `function`) has no attribute `cuda`, which is a method of [`nn.Model`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.cuda) *instances*.